# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: content-manager, 2011-sp1

When I right-click on a Publication and go to Properties, I suddenly started experiencing this error:

[image]

Upon inspecting the Event Viewer log on the CM server, the following stacktrace was found:

```
The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities' threw an exception.
The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities' threw an exception.
The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at _getFiberPtrId()
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at .cctor()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities..cctor()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.get_StoredProcedures()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities..cctor()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities..ctor()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDataSession..ctor()
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.DataSessionFactory.CreateDataSession()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.DataSessionFactory.CreateDataSession(UserData user)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataSession()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, String impersonationUserName)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String userName, String impersonationUserName, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Impersonate(String userName)
   at SyncInvokeImpersonate(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

When opening properties of SGs or Folders all seems normal.  Components, Pages, Templates and etc also open without issue.

Clearly something is funky with the DB, but what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the Database server had gone down the night before due to a hardware failure. After it had been restored, the `Tridion Content Manager Service Host` service had not been restarted.  After restarting all the Tridion services, all operation resumed to normal.